# TestNG XML File Not Getting Executed

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have a created a login test for my website using the TestNG framework in Java in Eclipse and want to execute my tests through an XML file by running it through the command prompt.

The name of the website I want to test is named My Website. The root folder of my project is `Test My Website` and the file system of my folder is illustrated in the following screenshot:

[image: Root folder structure]

I have followed the instructions as given over [here](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.in/2011/10/running-selenium-testng-test-from.html) and have arranged my project's file system accordingly.

PS: A `bin` folder also exists in my project's root which is used by the Java compiler to store the `.class` files but is not displayed in the Eclipse's Package Explorer.

The source code of the **TestClass1.java** is,

```
package testngsample;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class TestClass1 {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected static String result;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    void loginTest() {
        try {
            driver.get("https://test.rockon.me");
            driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("max_marchisio");
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("Rockon123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("GoArrow")).click();
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            result = driver.getTitle();
            Assert.assertEquals(result, "Home | RockON");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

The source code of the **TestNG.xml** file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="My sample Suite">
    <test name="Search test">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The problem here is that despite following the proper instructions as given in the link provided above, I am unable to execute the `TestNG.xml` file. In order to execute the file from command prompt, I am executing the following commands in my command prompt.

1) `cd C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\workspace\Test My Website`

2) `set ProjectPath="C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\workspace\Test My Website"`

3) `set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*`

4) `java -cp org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%TestNG.xml`

and get the following output (literally) in my command prompt,

```
Error: Could not load find or load main class C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\workspace\Test My Website"TestNG.xml
```

I am able to run the script by executing the **TestNG.xml file** through Eclipse by creating the TestNG run configuration for the file and it also produces the output and generates the reports perfectly, but why is this not happening from command prompt?

Can anyone please tell me where exactly am I going wrong? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think the error says it all: .xml files do not contain any java classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after banging my head on a brick wall, I finally found a workaround solution to the problem myself. I just changed my XML file to run the script for the package and not the individual class. Hence my **TestNG.xml** file has been changed to,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="My sample Suite">
    <test name="Search test">
        <packages>
            <package name="testngsample" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Also I set the classpath for my project from the command prompt by executing the following command,

```
java -cp "C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\workspace\Test My Website\lib\*;C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\workspace\Test My Website\bin" org.testng.TestNG TestNG.xml
```

Comment: You didn't need to change your `testng.xml` file. It was fine. As you determined, the issue was the command line needed to contain a reference to your code under test.

Comment: Yeah, it somehow seemed that my classpath had not been set properly. By executing the `java -cp` command and editing my `TestNG.xml` file as shown above, I got it working. Will try setting the classpath from the project and reverting my XML file changes now.